# Setting, Reading and Writing Cookie with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

In this example I am to ask the user for their name via a prompt, then use the cookie to write to a div, "Welcome, savedCookie!" after entering and then each time they visit the page before the expiration.

I get the browser to present a prompt asking for my name and then it writes to the div as "Welcome, undefined!" I can't figure out why I receive the error.

```js
//Setting cookie for Users Name
function set_it() {
    var userName = prompt("Please Enter Your Name", ""),
      thetext = "name=" + userName,
      expdate = ";expires=Mon, 27 Mar 2017 13:00:00 UTC",
      newtext = encodeURIComponent(thetext);
    newtext += expdate;
    document.cookie = newtext;
  }
  //Reading & Writing cookie

function read_it() {
  var rawCookie = document.cookie;
  bakedCookie = decodeURIComponent(rawCookie);
  yumCookie = bakedCookie.split("=");
  document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "<p>Welcome, " + yumCookie[1] + "!</p>";

}

if (document.cookie) {
  read_it();
} else {
  set_it();
  read_it();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="greeting">
    <script src="prjs13_2.js"></script>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your only this code in console and look what you get-

```
 var userName = prompt("Please Enter Your Name", ""),
      thetext = "name=" + userName,
      expdate = ";expires=Mon, 27 Mar 2017 13:00:00 UTC",
      newtext = encodeURIComponent(thetext);
    newtext += expdate;
    document.cookie = newtext;
```

I did it for the name "david" and i got this-

name%3Ddavid;expires=Mon, 27 Mar 2017 13:00:00 UTC"

when you are setting your cookie your name attribute is not valid.
try this code instead (without encodeURIComponent and ; instead of comma)-

```
var userName = prompt("Please Enter Your Name", "");
var  thetext = "name=" + userName;
var expdate = ";expires=Mon, 27 Mar 2017 13:00:00 UTC";
var newtext = thetext;
document.cookie = newtext;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did some more testing and it must be browser settings blocking the desired effect. I tested it in fiddle and it did exactly what I needed it to do, after that I tested it in Edge and also got the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function to get/set cookies:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
        user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("username", user, 365);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some fiddle example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NemanjaT/1ttqmjpg/)

Comment: While searching for an answer before posting this question, I came across this solution as well. However, I am doing this for a class out of a book and the book wants it to be done this way.

I did some more testing and it must be browser settings blocking the desired effect. I tested it in fiddle and it did exactly what I needed it to do, after that I tested it in Edge and also got the desired effect. Thank you for your reply though! Much appreciated!